# Unable to manipulate information of factory in controller

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Angular application. I need to create a database in SQLite to be used locally in my Android project. Every tutorial that I saw taught me to make it in a factory and call it in other pages.

The problem is, in a lot of situations, I need to take that information and manipulate it. I already was able to show it in the form, but unfortunately, I wasn't capable of manipulating the object returned from the factory.

My code is below.

Factory sqlite:

```
var db = null;
var clienteselec = [];
var sqlite = angular.module('sqlite', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

sqlite.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $window) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "rollers.db", location: 1 });

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes (id integer primary key, nome varchar(40))");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instalacao (id integer primary key, idCliente int, dataInst datetime)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS manutencao (id integer primary key, idCliente int, idInstalacao int, dataManut datetime)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipamento (id integer primary key, idInstalacao int, idManutencao int, TC int autoincrement, posicao varcar(1), Rolo varchar(40), dataEquip datetime)");
    });
})

sqlite.factory('clientesFactory', function ($cordovaSQLite, $rootScope) {
    return {
insert: function (Nome) {
            var query = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome) VALUES (?);";
            var values = [Nome];

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values).then(
              function (res) {
                  alert('Cliente Cadastro com Sucesso!');

                  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT max(id) as id from clientes", []).then(
                      function (res) {
                          if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                              var valores = res.rows.item(0);
                              $rootScope.idCliente = valores.id;
                          }
                      }
                  );
              },
              function (err) {
                  alert('Cliente não cadastrado. Estamos verificando o problema!');
              }
            );
        },

        selectTodos: function(tab){
            var query = "SELECT * FROM " + tab;

            clienteselec = [];
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[]).then(function (result) {
                if(result.rows.length){
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                        clienteselec.push(result.rows.item(i));
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log("no data found!");
                }
            }, function(err){
                console.log("error" + err);
            });
        },
});
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ClienteCtrl', ['clientesFactory', '$scope', '$state', '$window', '$rootScope', function (clientesFactory, $scope, $state, $window, $rootScope) {
    $scope.listaClientes = function() {
        clientesFactory.insert('teste');
        clientesFactory.selectTodos('clientes');
        $scope.seleciona = clienteselec;
    }
}])
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>

    <div ng-controller="ClienteCtrl">
        <button ng-click="listaClientes()">Novo Cliente</button>
        <!--<table>
            <tr ng-repeat="cli in clientes">
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>-->    
        <ion-item ng-repeat="cli in seleciona">
            {{cli.nome}}
            <button ng-click="cadastraCliente({{cli.id}})">Novo</button>
            <button ng-click="instala({{cli.id}}, {{cli.nome}})">Instalação</button>
            <button ng-click="excluiCliente({{cli.id}}, {{cli.nome}})">Excluir</button>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of architectural problems, but that is pretty normal when you are starting something new. :)

I'm considering that the base of working with the database works (which I didn't test), the overall approach of passing data to the controller by a global variable is wrong, please avoid this at all costs in the angular/javascript world.

You need to think more let's say modular or object oriented and try to encapsulate this. If you don't your code will be very fragile and prone to errors, since even the order of your scripts could break it.

I did some tweaks with your code see bellow:

The factory:

```
angular.module('sqlite', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'rollers.db', location: 1 });

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes (id integer primary key, nome varchar(40))');
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instalacao (id integer primary key, idCliente int, dataInst datetime)');
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS manutencao (id integer primary key, idCliente int, idInstalacao int, dataManut datetime)');
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipamento (id integer primary key, idInstalacao int, idManutencao int, TC int autoincrement, posicao varcar(1), Rolo varchar(40), dataEquip datetime)');
    });
})
//I will not recommend you to use rootScope like that.
//I added $q to work with the  $cordovaSQLite promises
.factory('clientesFactory', function ($cordovaSQLite, $q /*$rootScope*/) {

    //local variables, no needs to be global
    var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'rollers.db', location: 1 });

    //better approach for legibility
    return {
        insert: insert,
        selectTodos: selectTodos
    };

    function insert(Nome) {
        var query = 'INSERT INTO clientes (nome) VALUES (?);';
        var values = [Nome];

        //since this is a assynchronous method            
        //we can return this promise and let the caller lead with it
        return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values)
            .then(function () {

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                // returns the data in the promise sucess
                deferred.resolve('Cliente Cadastro com Sucesso!');

                /*
                //This is really necessary?
                //If so, why not to convert it in another method?
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT max(id) as id from clientes', []).then(
                    function (res) {
                        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                            var valores = res.rows.item(0);
                            $rootScope.idCliente = valores.id;
                        }
                    }
                );*/
            })
            .catch(function () { //promises have a catch method to capture the error
                //returns the data with error 
                deferred.reject('Cliente não cadastrado. Estamos verificando o problema!');

            });
    }

    function selectTodos(tab) {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tab;

        //since this is a assynchronous method            
        //we can return this promise and let the caller lead with it
        return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [])
            .then(function (result) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                if (!result.rows.length) {
                    //returns the data with error 
                    deferred.reject('No data found!');
                }

                var clienteselec = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    clienteselec.push(result.rows.item(i));
                }

                //returns the data in the promise sucess
                deferred.resolve(clienteselec);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {  //promises have a catch method to capture the error
                console.log('error' + err);
            });
    }
})
```

The controller:

```
.controller('ClienteCtrl', ['clientesFactory', '$scope', '$state', '$window', '$rootScope', function (clientesFactory, $scope, $state, $window, $rootScope) {

    $scope.listaClientes = listaClientes;
    $scope.seleciona = [];


    function listaClientes() {
        //Now, let the promise magic happens 
        //and lead with it here in the controller logic
        clientesFactory.insert('teste')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //use console.error to show erros :)
                console.error(err);
            });

        clientesFactory.selectTodos('clientes')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.clienteselec = response;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //use console.error to show erros :)
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
}]);
```

Hopefully, the view will not change at all:

```
<ion-content padding>

<div ng-controller="ClienteCtrl">
    <button ng-click="listaClientes()">Novo Cliente</button>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="cli in seleciona">
        {{ cli.nome }}
        <button ng-click="cadastraCliente({{cli.id}})">Novo</button>
        <button ng-click="instala({{cli.id}}, {{cli.nome}})">Instalação</button>
        <button ng-click="excluiCliente({{cli.id}}, {{cli.nome}})">Excluir</button>
</div>
```

A disclaimer: I do not run this code anywhere, so I'm pretty sure this will not work as it is. You will need to make the necessary adjustments, hopefully, this will give you an overall approach to how to pass data from your service (factory) to the controller, as well as some good programming practices. If you want to learn more on how to do an angular app the right way, I highly recommend you to check out the John Papa's Angular Style Guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you very much for your help gvsrepins. I will test the promises like you put there and will response if it worked.

Comment: I'm happy to help @FelipeF. :) If this answer fits the needs that you have please mark it as the answer to your question. Thanks.